# Is there a way to pivot data when one of the identifier values is NA?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have an example data

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3)), type = rep(c(3,3,NA),3), label = rep(c("test1", "test2", "test3"),3), value = rep(5:7,3))
```

I have X number of values in column `type`, and I want to pivot the values in my `label` and `value` columns. I have rows where `type` is NA, and in these instances, I would like the corresponding values in `label` and `value` to be seen across the rows that do have a value in `type`. When I use the `pivot_wider` function from the tidyverse package, I'm left with rows where `type` is NA and `test3` is NA:

```
test %>% pivot_wider(names_from = label, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
     ID  type test1 test2 test3
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     5     6    NA
2     1    NA    NA    NA     7
3     2     3     5     6    NA
4     2    NA    NA    NA     7
5     3     3     5     6    NA
6     3    NA    NA    NA     7
```

To solve this, I was looking into the tidyverse `complete` function, in order to get every combination of `type` and `label`, but this produces *every* combination, and I would only like to do this for label == test3, since this is where the NA `type` value is.

```
test %>% complete(label, value)
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   label value    ID  type
   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 test1     5     1     3
 2 test1     5     2     3
 3 test1     5     3     3
 4 test1     6    NA    NA
 5 test1     7    NA    NA
 6 test2     5    NA    NA
 7 test2     6     1     3
 8 test2     6     2     3
 9 test2     6     3     3
10 test2     7    NA    NA
11 test3     5    NA    NA
12 test3     6    NA    NA
13 test3     7     1    NA
14 test3     7     2    NA
15 test3     7     3    NA
```

I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do this? This is the output I'm looking for:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     ID  type test1 test2 test3
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     5     6     7
2     2     3     5     6     7
3     3     3     5     6     7
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not work for your real data, but it works for your example.

What we do is pivot wide, then group by ID, and then fill in NA values with other values in the group. This completes all the rows in the group, and we use distinct to remove the duplicates

```
test %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = label, values_from = value) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    fill(everything(), .direction='downup') %>%
    distinct()

     ID  type test1 test2 test3
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     5     6     7
2     2     3     5     6     7
3     3     3     5     6     7
```

You'll run into problems here if there are multiple values for each column within the ID. For example, this data has multiple values for `test2` within `ID==3`, and results in duplicated rows there:

```
test2
# A tibble: 7 × 5
     ID  type test1 test2 test3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     5     6    NA
2     1    NA    NA    NA     7
3     2     3     5     6    NA
4     2    NA    NA    NA     7
5     3     3     5     6    NA
6     3    NA    NA    NA     7
7     3    NA    NA     3    NA

test2 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    fill(everything(), .direction='downup') %>%
    distinct()

     ID  type test1 test2 test3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     5     6     7
2     2     3     5     6     7
3     3     3     5     6     7
4     3     3     5     3     7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pivot_wider(fill(test, type),  id_cols = c(ID, type),names_from = label)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
     ID  type test1 test2 test3
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     5     6     7
2     2     3     5     6     7
3     3     3     5     6     7
```

Comment: This would run into problems if the `type` wasn't all the same, I think. Since the data frame isn't grouped, it could fill in the missing type with the value from another group